# custom intermediate table django fetch the records

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have two models with M2M relation. The custom table is defined as with en extra field

```
class DoctorHospital(models.Model):
clinic = models.ForeignKey(ClinicHospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
shift = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

Problem is that I am trying to fetch all clinics based on a specific doctor. Data is come based on specific doctor but custom field **shift** does not come.

here is my class base view

```
class DoctorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Doctor
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['clinic_hospital_list'] = self.object.clinic_hospital.all()
    return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `clinic_hospital_list` to obtain the related `shift` value:

```
from django.db.models import F

class DoctorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Doctor
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['clinic_hospital_list'] = self.object.clinic_hospital.annotate(
            shift=F('doctorhospital__shift')
        )
        return context
```

Now the `ClinicHospital`s that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.shift` that holds the value of the `shift` field in the intermediate table.

Comment: thank so much, @WillemVanOnsem you always support me. Do you have any source from there I could learn all this type of subject?

Comment: @AliRazaJaveed: I think the section on [*query expressions*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/) might be a good start.